# How to create a foreground service from Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am creating a location based game and i want to create a foreground service from my Unity project. This foreground service will send the location of the user to our server.
I have managed to create a library that sends my current activity to the library but the problem is that i am unable to start a service from it.

Your help will greatly appreciated.

**Update**
I also using firebase FCM and analytics, So i printed out the logs i get firebase activity not unity activity can anyone help, i am noob at this so maybe it will be a noob mistake.

Here is my code:

**Android Library**

```
public static void RecieveActivityInstance(Activity temp)
{
    Log.d("XR Service", "RecieveActivityInstance: "+temp);
    _Activity = temp;
}

public static void StartMyService()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.abc.xy.location.customlibrary.CustomService");
    _Activity.startService(intent);
}
```

**Unity Script**

```
AndroidJavaClass unityClass;
AndroidJavaObject unityActivity;
AndroidJavaClass customClass;

private void Awake()
{

    sendActivityReference("com.abc.xy.location.customlibrary.Unity_Native_Event");
    startService();
}

void sendActivityReference(string packageName)
{
    unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    Debug.Log($"RecieveActivityInstance: {unityActivity.ToString()}");
    customClass = new AndroidJavaClass(packageName);
    customClass.CallStatic("RecieveActivityInstance", unityActivity);
}

void startService()
{
    customClass.CallStatic("StartMyService");
}
```